# How can I remove a flash from a changing slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website `https://acanhs.org/` but when the slideshow changes to another picture it shows a white flash. How can I remove it?

My html:

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

.mySlides {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-image: var(--background-image);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.mySlides>.numbertext {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.w3-animate-top {
  position: relative;
  animation: animatetop 0.4s
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.w3-animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  animation: animatebottom 0.4s
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container image">

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/81463156_472179973704673_8295529433598935850_n(1).jpg')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/097f1e08-ebfe-434a-bc68-8020d02cee6e.JPG')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/8291878a-b5ad-4003-8cc6-de7baafd84a0.JPG')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/27890996_211176766129569_6923967286697000960_n.jpg')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/42914143_364663130939605_1259772328364992140_n.jpg')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/42947322_373232869884042_7326776160519321694_n.jpg')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/44689929_944494762409958_8911408401400786089_n.jpg')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/fd2b6c09-19b7-42ad-b7fb-bce6dc983690.JPG')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/IMG_6922.jpg')">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/IMG_6932.jpg')">
  </div>


</div>
<br>
<br>
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
```

My question is how can I remove the white flash from the slideshow

Comment: what you call "flash" is simple your background, 
because the animation is not in sync

Comment: Any idea on how I can sync it? I'm new to web development and I'm really excited to learn new stuff

Comment: try putting the js code to view the image above the one that hides it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello can you start keyframe opacity from 1 not from 0?
It could then no transition progress from opacity 0 to 1 which shows flash thing during transtion.
So here is updated animation style.

```
.container{
    background-color:black;
  }
.w3-animate-top{position:relative;animation:animatetop 0.4s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:1} to{top:0;opacity:1}}

.w3-animate-bottom{position:relative;animation:animatebottom 0.4s}@keyframes animatebottom{from{bottom:-300px;opacity:1} to{bottom:0;opacity:1}}
```

Comment: By the way your background is white, you will still white space during transition.

Comment: Can't I make the transition faster so the white space doesn't show up? (sorry I'm a JavaScript noob)

Comment: If you really dont want white flash, why don't you set background of container to other color? eg black? Then no flash with above css. Just this is my humble opinion. :)

Comment: That's smart. Thanks I'll do that

Comment: I have updated css. Let me know if it could help. No other way to dismiss gap during transition btw. Please upvote or check if it helps you. thanks.